# Create sharepoint online page with mixed webparts and custom development

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, sharepoint-addin, custom, apps-development

I need to build a page in sharepoint online that has two native sharepoint webparts: calendar and documents.

Also, i need to make some kind of custom development, because i was to give the user to make certain actions to the events in the calendar list (such as marking thinks done in a to-do list).

I was thinking i could develop a custom webpart and put it in a page, next to the other webparts, but i see that webparts are being deprecated in sharepoint, and being replaced with add-ins? Is this right?

So, if i have to create an add-in, can i create it and blend it in a page with native sharepoint webparts or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting the web parts development for SharePoint online site better you can start with SharePoint Client Side web Parts (SharePoint Framework -
 SPFx).

This can be built with all open source JavaScript libraries. You can choose one of the preferred JavaScript libraries (jQuery, React, Angular and etc..). This new web part model addressed issues in APP development.

This Framework already in general availability and support modern sites and classic sites.

You can read below articles to get started with development.

[Why SharePoint Framework](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Why-SPFx)

[SharePoint framework Samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts)

Comment: so, can I still build webparts? Aren't they being deprecated by microsoft?

Comment: In SharePoint online Sandbox web parts were deprecated. Now if you want to build any web part approaches are 1) building a JavaScript solution and add them using Content Editor/Script Editor web parts 2) Build SharePoint Hosted Apps / Provided Hosted Apps and add these using App Parts 3) Created a client side web parts using SharePoint Framework tool chain. This is latest architecture to build web parts.

Comment: I'm trying to build a app part (SharePoint hosted) with JavaScript code. But when I put it in a page it doesn't work (because of cross domain error...it's a SharePoint hosted app part...).but thank you for your reply. I'll add another question with this situation.

Comment: Thanks Venkat - I have exactly the same question. I did some Visual Studio custom development 5+ years ago on a private SharePoint system and now have to do the same for a client who uses SPO